# Show only first couple of paragraphs. Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using simple_format(@company.description) to make a text into a number of paragraphs. On one page I only want to show, lets say, the first three paragraphs. Is there any nifty ruby method that can help out here or should I read up on my regular expression skills, which are very out of date.

Cheers Carl

Answer (score 0):

The [truncate helper method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) takes an optional `:separator`. Since simple_format uses `<br />` tags to indicate paragraphs, you should be able to do something like this:

```
truncate(simple_format(@company.description), length: 3, separator: '<br />')
```

Answer (score -2):

Personally, I'd round the text before putting it into a formatter. I'd assume you have a \r\n or \n in your text.   Why format 1000 paragraphs if all you need is the first 3.

```
def get_first_paragraphs(text, desired = 3)
   text.each_with_index do |character, index| 
      if(character == "\n")
         desiredParCount -= 1
         return text[0..index] if(desiredParCount <= 0)
      end
   end
   return text;
end
```

It's a function sure, but it's the fastest method.. if speed is important.  (it always is, ALWAYS!) :)